# How can cpp show 2 different values at the same memory location after using const_cast on a const int variable

Tags: c++, memory-management, const-cast

I am trying to change the value of a `const int` variable (should not be done ideally). This is how I did it.

```
const int x{5};               //line 1
int* y{const_cast<int*>(&x)}; //line 2

std::cout<<y<<" "<<&x<<endl;  //line 3

*y = 10;                      //line 4
std::cout<<*y<<" "<<x<<endl;  //line 5
std::cout<<y<<" "<<&x<<endl;  //line 6
```

At line 2, I took away the constness of the constant variable `x` and made `y` point to it.

At line 3, the memory address of `y` and `x` are same.

But, after I changed the value of `y` at line 4, line 5 prints `*y=10` and `x=5`, and the weird thing is line 6 still shows the same memory address of `y` and `x`.

Can anyone help me understand how things are working internally?

I only want to understand the cause of how the program shows 2 different values at the same memory location.

Comment: Why are you trying to change a constant if they are created to not be changed just to be readed?

Comment: What did you expect to happen when you do something that is not allowed? You are experiencing undefined behaviour here, anything is allowed to happen. Probably `x` got inlined in line 5.

Comment: Modifying const object produces _undefined behavior_. If you want to know what your implementation does internally, study the generated assembly. Exemplary demo: https://godbolt.org/z/6hceYfj16.

Comment: @churill, I expected the same value of *y and x as the memory locations are same. Isn't this what should have happened?

Comment: @RajKumarSingh Undefined behavior = anything can happen = nothing particular should happen

Comment: @RajKumarSingh "*I expected the same value of `*y` and `x`*" - why did you expect *writing* to a *read-only* object would yield *any* meaningful results at all? You broke the rules, so this is a consequence.

Comment: How things are working internally? The compiler probably assumes that as x is constant, it doesn't need to access the memory location allocated for x in line 5, and just print 5.